# Immersive mode in Fragment Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

How do I keep the immersive mode when I show you a fragment dialog. I have created a class that inherits from dialog fragment but not working.

Answer (score 0):

In Dialog or BottomSheetDialogFragment you have to implement this solution which is work for me.

Step 1:

In your dialog or BottomSheetDialog, write this code in onActivityCreated method,

```
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
var viewParent = view
while (viewParent is View) {
    viewParent.fitsSystemWindows = false
    viewParent.setOnApplyWindowInsetsListener { _, insets -> insets }
    viewParent = viewParent.parent as View?
 }
}
```

Step 2: Also, override the below method :

```
override fun setupDialog(dialog: Dialog, style: Int) {

 super.setupDialog(dialog, style)
    dialog?.window?.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, 
 WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE)

}
```

Now see the magic :)

Answer (score -1):

Override on onCreateDialog.

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
    dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALT_FOCUSABLE_IM | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                    | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    dialog.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    dialog.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    dialog.setContentView(root);
    dialog.getWindow().setLayout(500, 500);

    return dialog;
}
```

I made fixed size. Refer to this hack in, http://vardhan-justlikethat.blogspot.com/2014/06/android-immersive-mode-for-dialog.html